# What is the recommended way to iterate a GNU Trove TObjectIntHashMap by decreasing value?

Tags: java, trove4j

GNU Trove / trove4j TObjectIntHashMap is great for counting String occurences:

```
TObjectIntHashMap<Integer> map = new TObjectIntHashMap<>();
map.adjustOrPutValue(string, 1, 1);
```

Now a common task is to ask for the string with the highest count or iterate by decreasing count. How would you do this?

Thank you,
Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no special operations for this in `TObjectIntHashMap`. To get the entry with max value, iterate through all entries:

```java
class GetMaxEntry implements TObjectIntProcedure {
    Object key;
    int value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public boolean execute(Object k, int v) {
        if (v >= value) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
GetMaxEntry getMaxEntry = new GetMaxEntry();
map.forEachEntry(getMaxEntry);
//process(getMaxEntry.key, getMaxEntry.value);
```

To iterate by decreasing count, the only thing you can do is to dump entries into a collection or array of, say, `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`s (or special Entry class with primitive value field) using the same `forEachEntry` operation and then sort by `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` with custom `Comparator`.

Comment: Thank you leventov, yeah I feared this is the only way, but this would require to create a copy of the map so one loses the performance there again.

Answer (score 1):

As @leventov said, you'd currently need to iterator through the entire collection as sorted collections don't currently exist in Trove. There is a feature request [here](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/issue/11) that you could vote on if this is interesting to you.